# How to transform a list of tables into a list of dataframes without changing the formats of the tables?

Tags: r, dataframe, datatables, lapply, frequency

I have this list (all we care that it is a list of 2 tables)

```
set.seed(222)
df = data.frame(x = trunc(runif(10,0,2)),
                y = trunc(runif(10,4,6)),
                z = trunc(runif(10,19,21)),
                m = trunc(runif(10,28,30)))
df


t1 = table(df$x,df$y)
t2=table(df$z,df$m)


L = list(t1,t2)
```

when I apply `lapply` as follows

```
lapply(L,as.data.frame)
```

I have this outcome

```
[[1]]
  Var1 Var2 Freq
1    0    4    0
2    1    4    2
3    0    5    5
4    1    5    3

[[2]]
  Var1 Var2 Freq
1   19   28    2
2   20   28    3
3   19   29    3
4   20   29    2
```

I tried to include the function `spread` to fix this problem but did not work with me. would appreciate the help

Answer (score 3):

The `table` object can be converted to `matrix` and to a `data.frame` so that it will keep the same structure

```
L1 <- lapply(L, as.data.frame.matrix)
```

-output

```
> str(L1)
List of 2
 $ :'data.frame':   2 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ 4: int [1:2] 4 3
  ..$ 5: int [1:2] 2 1
 $ :'data.frame':   2 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ 28: int [1:2] 3 1
  ..$ 29: int [1:2] 2 4
> L1
[[1]]
  4 5
0 4 2
1 3 1

[[2]]
   28 29
19  3  2
20  1  4
```

---

If we need `proportions`

```
lapply(L, \(x) 100 *as.data.frame.matrix(proportions(x)))
```

Comment: do you know how to transoform these resulted dataframes into percentages dataframes ?

Comment: @Anas116 trt the update

Comment: you always help me. Really appreciate that.

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you so much master! `as.data.frame.matrix` quite new to me!